# how to create a list of lists

Tags: python, list

My Python code generates a list everytime it loops:

```
list = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('floatname','float')], skip_header=1)
```

But I want to save each one - I need a list of lists right?

So I tried:

```
list[i] = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('floatname','float')], skip_header=1)
```

But Python now tells me that "list" is not defined. I'm not sure how I go about defining it. Also, is a list of lists the same as an array??

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your entire loop, not just the line that performs the assignment.

Comment: it is a BAD idea to create a variable that is the same name as a builtin.

Comment: An array is not a list of lists. "array" has different meanings in different languages (in C an array cannot be resized, in Perl one can) but in most cases it is roughly analogous to a regular Python list.

Comment: Show an example of the file 'temp.txt', and explain what you want the result in python to look like.

Comment: It is a BAD idea to create a language which permits willy-nilly variables to redefine builtins.  Unless the aim of the language is to allow others to rewrite the language using the language because the language is poorly designed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use append method, eg:

```
lst = []
line = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('floatname','float')], skip_header=1)
lst.append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I only used "list" as an example, but I see that I should have used something else. So I got this working as you suggested. Now when I print list[0] or list[7] etc., I get the right answer. But when I try and print the whole thing with print list, I get a weird looking readout with the word "array" and "dtype" in it.

Answer (score 55):

You want to create an empty list, then append the created list to it.  This will give you the list of lists.  Example:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append([1,2,3])
>>> l.append([4,5,6])
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: That's good but I struggle to understand why the below has a different result:          
    >>> l=[1,2,3]
    >>> l.append([4,5,6])
    >>> l
    [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: Maybe this helps?  
>>> l=[[1,2,3]]
>>> l.append([4,5,6])
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: @user222216 if you want to sum lists use + , otherwise what you did, is on position 0->1, on position 1->2, on position 2->3, and finally you put on position 3 whole list-> [4,5,6]

Answer (score 9):

Create your list before your loop, else it will be created at each loop.

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> for i in range(10) :
...   list1.append( range(i,10) )
...
>>> list1
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9], [9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all ***do not*** use `list` as a variable name- that is a builtin function.

I'm not super clear of what you're asking (a little more context would help), but maybe this is helpful-

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('floatname','float')], skip_header=1))
my_list.append(np.genfromtxt('temp2.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('floatname','float')], skip_header=1))
```

That will create a list (a type of mutable array in python) called `my_list` with the output of the `np.getfromtext()` method in the first 2 indexes.

The first can be referenced with `my_list[0]` and the second with `my_list[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same issue today...

In order to create a list of lists you will have firstly to store your data, array, or other type of variable into a list. Then, create a new empty list and append to it the lists that you just created. At the end you should end up with a list of lists:

```
list_1=data_1.tolist()
list_2=data_2.tolist()
listoflists = []
listoflists.append(list_1)
listoflists.append(list_2)
```