# How to convert a list into list of lists?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list of numbers:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I found how to create a list of lists:

```
new_L = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]]
```

But that is not what I need. I need to create (x) times (y) list of lists. For example, as a 3 times 4 list of lists:

```
new_L_2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Or a 2*6 list of lists:

```
new_L_3 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

How can I make it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a list comprehension which uses slices. Seems like homework. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think this question may have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293208/how-to-create-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: using numpy [list to 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575421/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `range` to get `x` number of element. For example you want 4 elements use

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
out = [l[i: i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 4)]

print(out)
```

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you would break this down if you were to draw it out on paper.

You need to create a function that iterates through a list of numbers. There a plenty of ways to do this, but one from the top of my head is as follows.

Create a function that takes an input list and an integer (X) for how many items in each sub-list. Iterate through each item in the list and add it to a temporary list. If the index of the list item is divisible by X, append the temporary list to the list of lists, empty the temporary list, and start again.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
x = 3
y = 4

newList = []

for i in range(x):
    newList.append([L[t+(i*y)] for t in range(y)])

print(newList)
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does.

Comment: it will generate a list and append that list as an element. the x and y are parameters. you can see the full question above